# How can I create a virtual environment in which there will be no python libraries?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to have an empty virtual environment where there will be no python modules or libraries that had installed before. I use git bash for this. I create it and activate, but when I use pip list or pip freeze I see all the libraries I have on my PC. What do I do wrong? Thank you.

[image: Here is a print screen, that shows my actions.]

Comment: Having that as text instead of a screenshot would be more helpful…

Answer (score 0):

In order to view the packages in the virtualenv only, you need to use `pip list --local` (or `pip freeze --local`) instead of `pip list` (or `pip freeze`)